# Prometheus integration with Central/Master Netdata server

Tags: prometheus, netdata

I am having a master/central Netdata server which is aggregating the metrics from the slave Netdata agents.

I want to setup Prometheus server to query data out of the master/central Netdata server instead of the individual Netdata agents.

Let me know whether I am setting it up correctly or I should let the individual Netdata agents to fetch data to the Prometheus.

I am using this approach to make the Netdata agents secure, as from Netdata master to Netdata agents communication happens using token.